# Android - Show/Hide indicator next to TextView or Button

Tags: android, button, textview, show-hide, indicator

I have some buttons/textviews which when clicked, some layouts are shown or hidden. I want to add a show/hide indicator at the left of these buttons/textviews but I can't seem to find a way. I tried using text characters like ( ▼ )programmatically but I get a message from Eclipse about character encoding. (plus it's not a very visually elegant solution). The ideal would be something like this. which is offered by the Expandable ListView. How can I make a textview or button have a style like this?

[image: expandable listView indicator]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an ImageView, there are [official icon packs](https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html) where you can find an `ic_action_collapse.png` and `ic_action_expand`.

(You can find in them in the folders `02_navigation_expand` and `02_navigation_collapse`) in dark and light and the 4 resolution variants (`mdpi`, `hdpi`, `xhdpi` and `xxhdpi`).

Just copy the directories into your `res` folder and the correct resolution will be picked by android automaticall.